# Fancybox on ANdroid always opens window at top of page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a problem when viewing Fancybox on an Android mobile phone. If I have an image at the bottom of a long page and I press on it, Fancybox always opens it at the top of the page, which means I have to scroll all the way up to see it. Is there a way to make it open in the area I click it at?
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: any code or a link to the site with the issue would be helpful

Comment: Make sure you have updated to the latest (currently v2.0.6)

Comment: yes that was the problem Janis, I was using v2.0.4. Thanks.